# How to compare 2 values with client-side validation in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

How to compare 2 values?
Value `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstSetList[i].Amount)` must be divisible by `@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstSetList[i].Pack)`. If not then user will see information before he will press button SUBMIT. So I need to use client-side validation. But I don't know how. Probably with javascript but i'm beginner and I don't have any experience with JS.

Model:

```
public class PriceViewModel
    {
     public int Name { get; set; }
     public int Pack{ get; set; }
     public int Amount { get; set; }
    }
```

View:

```
// ...........
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < Model.FirstSetList.Count; i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstSetList[i].Name)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.FirstSetList[i].Name)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstSetList[i].Pack)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.FirstSetList[i].Pack)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstSetList[i].Amount)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstSetList[i].Amount)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
            <input type="submit" value="Confirm" class="btn btn-success" />
        }
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: You need a custom `ValidationAttribute` that implements `IClientValidatable` and `jquery` methods to add the validation rules to the `jquery.validator. Refer [THE COMPLETE GUIDE TO VALIDATION IN ASP.NET MVC 3 - PART 2](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2)

Answer (score 0):

You can write your validation attribute and js function to check all you need. [This link can help you.](https://thewayofcode.wordpress.com/tag/custom-unobtrusive-validation/)